# Suggested resources for learning about blocks

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch, osx-snow-leopard

What are some good suggested resources for learning about blocks and GCD in Mac OS X and iOS

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would start with Apple's [Blocks Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH1-SW1) document or with [Programming with Blocks on Apple Devices](http://thirdcog.eu/pwcblocks/). As gs mentioned, also check out Mike Ash's articles (and also subscribe to his RSS feed, as I'm sure more blocks-related posts will come up):

- [Friday Q&A 2008-12-26](http://www.mikeash.com/?page=pyblog/friday-qa-2008-12-26.html)
- [Friday Q&A 2009-08-14: Practical Blocks](http://www.mikeash.com/?page=pyblog/friday-qa-2009-08-14-practical-blocks.html)
- [Friday Q&A 2009-08-28: Intro to Grand Central Dispatch Part 1](http://www.mikeash.com/?page=pyblog/friday-qa-2009-08-28-intro-to-grand-central-dispatch-part-i-basics-and-dispatch-queues.html)

Answer (score 6):

There is a great introduction at bbum's weblog:
[Basic Blocks](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/08/29/basic-blocks/)

Answer (score 5):

Mike Ash has written two articles about blocks in his blog:

1. [Friday Q&A 2008-12-26](http://www.mikeash.com/?page=pyblog/friday-qa-2008-12-26.html)
2. [Friday Q&A 2009-08-14: Practical Blocks](http://www.mikeash.com/?page=pyblog/friday-qa-2009-08-14-practical-blocks.html)

In a third article he wrote about Grand Central Dispatch, which is also using blocks:
[Friday Q&A 2009-08-28: Intro to Grand Central Dispatch, Part I: Basics and Dispatch Queues](http://www.mikeash.com/?page=pyblog/friday-qa-2009-08-28-intro-to-grand-central-dispatch-part-i-basics-and-dispatch-queues.html)

Answer (score 2):

This is a good introduction, and explains how to use a gcc patch to experiment with blocks under Leopard too:

[Blocks Examples: NSOperationQueue and UIActionSheet](http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/iphone/Using_Blocks_1.20090704.html)

Comment: ...and to that we should add Plausible Blocks as a way to get experimenting with blocks even on Leopard: http://code.google.com/p/plblocks/

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to pay the $300, the [WWDC Mac session videos](http://developer.apple.com/products/videos.html) include several sessions on blocks and Grand Central Dispatch.  The new APIs made possible by using blocks are also scattered throughout the remaining sessions that describe what's new in Snow Leopard.

Comment: I've been umming and ahhing over these. I suppose I should just bite the bullet.

Comment: If you're at all serious about developing for the iPhone or Mac, each of the tracks are well worth the money.  They're full of practical information, and the demos really show off the new technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a bit more to my own question.

Blocks and GCD have been around for a couple of years now, so the online docs have been supplemented by other online resources. Even some of the iOS teaching books cover the subject.

However, the new book by Mark Dalrymple [Advanced Mac OS X Programming](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Advanced-Mac-OSX-Programming-Guides/dp/0321706250/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1315509959&sr=1-3) has a couple of deeper chapters on Blocks and GCD that are of interest.