# Why does using an STL std::vector as a __block variable cause memory corruption?

Tags: memory-management, vector, block, objective-c++, vmat

After some time and effort I have tracked down a memory smashing bug in my code to this function. I stopped the memory smashing by replacing the two `__block vector<int>` variables with the combination of stack-allocated arrays to provide the storage and a `{klist|dlist}Ptr` variables to allow code inside the block to access the arrays (seen in the commended-out code below). This makes me fairly confident that it is indeed the use of `__block vector<int>` that is problematic.

```
void
traceTree(Matrix<double> Z, double s[3], int k, unsigned int depth)
{
    int m = Z.size(1) + 1;
    __block vector<int> klist(m, 0);
    // int klist[m]; int * klistPtr = klist;
    // klist[0] = k;
    __block vector<int> dlist(1, depth);
    // int dlist[depth]; int * dlistPtr = dlist;
    // dlist[0] = depth;
    __block int topk = 0;
    int currk = 0;

    void (^ subtree)(int i) = ^(int i) {
        if (i > m) {                // If it's not a leaf...
            topk += 1;
            klist[topk] = i - m;
            dlist[topk] = depth - 1;
        }
    };

    while (currk <= topk) {
        k = klist[currk];
        depth = dlist[currk];
        s[0] += Z[{2,k}];            // Sum of the edge lengths so far
        s[1] += Z[{2,k}] * Z[{2,k}]; // ... and the sum of the squares
        s[2] += 1;                   // ... and the count of the edges
        if (depth > 0) {
            subtree(Z[{0,k}]);       // Consider left subtree
            subtree(Z[{1,k}]);       // Consider right subtree
        }
        currk += 1;
    }
}
```

[I should point out, this is a purely iterative algorithm; there's no recursion. The block exists only to avoid duplicating the code needed to handle left and right subtrees.]

The obvious question is, why are the STL `vector` objects causing memory corruption here? They are not even doing any dynamic resizing… Is it simply not supported to use a C++ object as a `__block` variable?

Comment: Can you just show the code that is crashing? It is impossible to understand what you're asking about when you're showing some other code. You do `int * klistPtr = klist;` How would that work when `klist` is a `vector<int>`? In your code your block is capturing `klistPtr` and `dlistPtr`, not a `vector`.

Comment: Good point; I've edited the question as you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless it's a typo, I see your initialization of `dlist` being different from the array: `vector<int> dlist(1, depth);` makes a vector of length 1, not `depth`. This may possibly cause going out of bounds.

You can always guard against accessing vector elements out of bounds by using `dlist.at(currk)` instead of `dlist[currk]`, for both reading and writing.

Answer (score 0):

C++ objects are allowed as `__block` variables (though personally I would recommend lambdas if you're writing C++; there's not much reason IMO to use blocks in pure C++ like this).

`__block` C++ variables are copied using the copy constructor (see [C++ Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW6) in Block Programming Topics). It's possible you're overflowing your stack due to too many copies of large stack variables if this goes very deep (that would match your "memory corruption" symptom).

But again, I'd recommend lambdas rather than blocks for C++; see [@sellibitze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2396241/97337) at [How do Clang 'blocks' work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395040/how-do-clang-blocks-work) for some more discussion.

Comment: The algorithm doesn't recurse; it descends the tree iteratively, essentially using `klist` and `dlist` for the storage a recursive algorithm would need on the stack. Your point about **C++** lambdas is a good one, but I would still like to know what is happening in the code using blocks. (You can't dispatch a **C++** lambda via GCD; I'm not doing that in this algorithm, but I will be using that idiom a lot in other code.)